# python pandas assign yyyy-mm-dd from multiple years into accumulated week numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, week-number

Given a file with the following columns:

```
date, userid, amount
```

where `date` is in yyyy-mm-dd format.  I am trying to use python pandas to assign yyyy-mm-dd from multiple years into accumulated week numbers.  For example:

```
2017-01-01  => 1
2017-12-31  => 52
2018-01-01  => 53

df_counts_dates=pd.read_csv("counts.csv")

print (df_counts_dates['date'].unique())

df = pd.to_datetime(df_counts_dates['date'])

print (df.unique())


print (df.dt.week.unique())
```

since the data contains Aug 2017-Aug 2018 dates, the above returns

```
[33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52  1  2  3  4  5
  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
 31 32]
```

I am wondering if there is any easy way to make the first date "week 1", and make the week number accumulate across years instead of becoming 1 at the beginning of each year?

Comment: Weeks are a spooky thing as they break differently in the end of the year. I think the answer jezrael gives is a good start if you are ok with that.

Answer (score 3):

I believe need a bit different approach - subtract all values of column by first, timedeltas convert to [`days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html), floor divide by `7` and last `1` for not starting by `0`:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-08-01', periods=365)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': rng, 'a': range(365)})  
print (df.head())
        date  a
0 2017-08-01  0
1 2017-08-02  1
2 2017-08-03  2
3 2017-08-04  3
4 2017-08-05  4

w = ((df['date'] - df['date'].iloc[0]).dt.days // 7 + 1).unique()
print (w)
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
 49 50 51 52 53]
```

Comment: @smci - Do you think in sample data? OP use datetimes in days, so sample data too.